# Angular 2 : trying to update ngModel with onModelChange inside the controller

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to update `ngModel` inside `onModelChange`

I know we can do something like that :

```
<input [ngModel]="myValue" (ngModelChange)="myValue = $event" />
```

But this is not what I'm looking for. I need to do some validation before updating `myValue`

Here is my code :

```
<input mdInput type="number" 
       [ngModel]="tax.refundAmount" 
       (ngModelChange)="onChange($event, tax.paidAmount)" />
```

And in the controller :

```
onChange($event, maxValue) {
    if ($event > maxValue) {
        $event = maxValue;
    }
}
```

But the ngModel is not updated :(

How can I update the model inside the controller ? **The input shown up here is inside a `ngFor` loop so I cannot access the model directly**

**edit:**

I tried with `[(ngModel)]` and `(change)` but there are timing problem when emiting the event to the parent controller

**UPDATE 1**

I want to do something inside the component class **after** updating the model, like emitting an event or computing values. Therefore I cannot return the value and then update the model in the template.

Comment: Is `$event` really a `number`?

Comment: yes, should be.
`export class Tax {
 paidAmount: number;
 refundAmount: number;
 currency: string;
 type: string;
}`
I'll try to force a cast to int

Comment: Did you try passing `tax` to the `function` and setting `tax.refundAmount` instead? Or will this cause and infinite loop?

Comment: Yes I also tried that but still no update :/

Comment: (change)="onChange'()' ? (input)="onChange()" ?

Comment: when using `(change)` (look at the edit), the event is trigger before the update of the model. What does `(input)` do ?

Comment: for the (input) see: https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/event_oninput.asp

Comment: I think, what you need is directive, that intercepts the keydown and not (ngModel)

Comment: @Rebouste, what do you think about what I suggested above. Have you found a soultion? Do you need more help?

Comment: I have put an ID in my taxes object so I can filter the array and update the object. I'm leaving this open because I think it might be useful for other people (and me) to know how to update the ngModel inside the controller

Answer (score 2):

Try this?

```
<input mdInput type="number" 
               [ngModel]="tax.refundAmount" 
               (ngModelChange)="tax.refundAmount = onChange($event, tax.paidAmount, tax.refundAmount)" />
```

And your controller:

```
onChange($event, maxValue, refundAmount) {
    return $event > maxValue ? maxValue : refundAmount;
}
```

Comment: Didn't try it because I need to emit an @Output() after updating the value. But it should work for other cases, I guess

Comment: Then emit the value before returning it in the onChange method? But frankly, your better solution would be to go reactive.

Comment: If I emit before returning the value, the model will not be updated when emit function on parent component is call

Comment: I think you might want to add more of your source to your issue.... You have an event emitter, on which you call next. That should not prevent your return within your component from executing?

Comment: I have updated my question. I will learn reactive forms because I've never tried it. It looks like a good solution if a need to dynamically update my inputs when an other has changed